# WSO2 Python Script Mediator

Tags: python, mediator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to use a Script Mediator in WSO2 that has the following definition:

```
<script xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" language="py" key="myPythonScript" function="process"/>
```

I had to hard-code the "py" as language since Javascript, Ruby, and Groovy were the only options available in the language drop down list, although the WSO2 ScriptMediator documentation states that Python is supported.

When I try to save my proxy changes I get the error "ERROR - ScriptMediator No script engine found for language: py"

Is Python, in fact, unsupported in WSO2 in the ScriptMediator?  Or do I need to modify something somewhere to enable processing of Python scripts?

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556340/how-to-call-python-script-file-from-wso2-proxy-services, which has similar context.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put the python script library dependency jar inside ESB_HOME/repository/component/lib. Then you will be able to save the proxy and use it.

Comment: What exactly is the 'python script dependency jar' that I need to include in component/lib?  Can you point me to any documentation or examples that go through this process?  The only mention of a dependency that I've seen through an online search is jython.  Thank you.