# How to call python script file from wso2 proxy services

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

How to call python script file from wso2 proxy service.

We tried with send mediator to call the python script file which is located in my local machine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="FilepythonTest"
       transports="http https"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <description/>
   <target >
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="local:///Users/vikashsaharan/Desktop/python/testpy.py"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

We are unable to call with this call. Please guide me how can i call python script from wso2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [class mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Class+Mediator) and execute a python script from there. Following is a sample class mediator that would do this.

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        String command = "python /path/to/script.py";
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String ret = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("value is : "+ret);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You can refer [Running a .py file from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267391/running-a-py-file-from-java/27267509)

Answer (score 7):

WSO2 EI has the inbuilt capability to execute a python script using the [Script mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Script+Mediator). Following is a sample configuration.

```html
**sample api configuration** 

<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="api" context="/api-context">
   <resource methods="POST GET">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="Message" value="Before transformation"/>
         </log>
         <script language="py" key="conf:/repository/script/stockquoteTransformResponse.py" function="transformRequest"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="Message" value="After transformation"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

```js
**stockquoteTransformResponse.py file saved in carbon registry.**

from org.apache.synapse.util.xpath import SynapseXPath

def transformRequest(mc):
    symbolXPath = SynapseXPath("//*[local-name()='Code']/text()")
    symbol = symbolXPath.stringValueOf(mc)
    mc.setPayloadXML('''
 <m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples">
  <m:request>
   <m:symbol>''' + symbol + '''</m:symbol>
  </m:request>
 </m:getQuote>''')
```

We need to add the jython jar to **WSO2EI_HOME/lib** directory. This was tested with jython-2.2.1.jar from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/python/jython/2.2.1/jython-2.2.1.jar

Following output can be seen once we invoke the above api.
[image]

Comment: we can use only for payload set or every python functionality .